# Change Microsoft Outlook 2010 folders sorting order

Tags: vba, vb.net, outlook

When you open Microsoft Outlook 2010 you see folders sorting like this;

```
Inbox

Drafts

Sent Items

Deleted Items
```

I need a vb.net code which makes Microsoft Outlook 2010 folders sorting like this;

```
Sent Items

Inbox

Drafts

Deleted Items
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Folders collection is not sorted in any particular way. And, unlike the Items collection,  there is no Folders.Sort method. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephen_griffin/2013/11/08/mapi-provider-sorting/ for more information on how Outlook sorts the folders.